# How do I export column names to a file in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have been trying to export column names from postgres/redshift table to a file using below query:

```
COPY (select * from ios.rating where false) 
TO '/Users/xxx/ios-rating-file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

is there a way I could export column names from redshift either to file or just in the IDE?

Comment: which IDE do you use?

Comment: With Postgres, this does create a file with column names.

Comment: @Jon it is datagrip

Answer (score 1):

To get all column names of a table, you can use the *pg_table_def* Table in Redshift.

For example, to extract all column names of a table:

```
SELECT "column",
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE tablename = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

Regarding your query - the Redshift COPY command is used to insert data into Redshift. To export data from Redshift, you need to use the UNLOAD command to write files to S3. 
You can read more here: [AWS docs Redshift Unload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html)

If you have an IDE like Datagrip you can run the query above on the "pg_table_def" table and just copy/paste the column names manually if it's a one time usage.

Comment: I am using datagrip and I am not able to see any info from pg_table_def. It must be a permission issue.
I have also looked into UNLOAD command but couldn't figure out a way to export only columns. It has also a limitation on using `limit`

Comment: I am not able to use this : `UNLOAD ('select * from ios.rating limit 5') s3 <> iam <>`

Answer (score 0):

`select * from svv_all_columns`

**svv_all_tables** will give you additional information like whether it is a view or a table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_ALL_COLUMNS.html